# I want to delete the uploaded photos in angular project m doing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

this is my service I have created. fetch photos was already done and I need to delete what was fetched. As you all can clearly c that m just copying the code for fetching and uploading in delete section of the code.

```
this.fetchPhotos = function(userId){
    if(userId)
        return photo.customPOST({id: userId}, 'findByUserId');
    else
        return photo.customPOST(userId, 'findByUserId');    
};

/**
 *
 */
this.deletePhotos = function(userId){
    if(userId)
        delete photo.customPOST ({id: userId}, 'findByUserId');
    else
        delete photo.customPOST (userId, 'findByUserId');
};
```

this is the controller

```
    $scope.uploadBannerPhoto = function(file,folder){
        if(file.files.length <= 0) return;
        PhotoServices.upload2S3(file.files[0],folder).then(function(data){
            $scope.card.images = $scope.card.images || {};
            if(folder == 'banner'){
                $scope.card.images.bannerURL = data.url;
            }else{
                $scope.card.images.profileURL = data.url;
            }
               UserDetailsServices.updateUserInfo($scope.card).then(function(status){
            console.info('Saving: '+status);
        },function(err){
            console.error('updateUserInfo:'+err);
        });
    },function(err){
        console.error(err);
    });
}

$scope.deleteBannerPhoto = function(file,folder){
    if(file.files.length <= 0) return;
    PhotoServices.deletePhotos(file.files[0],folder).then(function(data){
        $scope.card.images = $scope.card.images || {};
        if(folder == 'banner'){
            $scope.card.images.bannerURL = data.url;
            delete data.url;
        }else{
            $scope.card.images.profileURL = data.url;
            delete data.url;
        }
           UserDetailsServices.updateUserInfo($scope.card).then(function(status){
            console.info('Saving: '+status);
        },function(err){
            console.error('updateUserInfo:'+err);
        });
    },function(err){
        console.error(err);
    });
}
```

the upload is working but not the delete... any solution as m just a newbie to angular or javascript but my project requires me to work on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's done use (remove "location to the pic")